# Which function I have to call on a Cancel button in a user interface (activity)?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have various activitys on my app. I have a configuration Activity, and I want to put a cancel button, that, when user press this button, the configuration window get's closed and turn back into the previous activity.

I found something about calling cancel or dismiss functions, but I can't call them cause this is not a dialog, it's an activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [finish](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish%28%29) an activity.

Comment: if i finish the activity, it will return to the previous activity without loss data and without any problems?

Comment: `finish()` simply finishes (well, duh) the current activity, thus moving back to the activity that was before. Anything else (storing persistent data, for example) is up to you.